# How to get a list of all valid ip address in a local network in android

Tags: android

I can find gateway address and netmask address in android. How to get a list of all valid ip address in a local network in android with this gateway and netmask?

Comment: What do you call 'a valid ip address'? The whole pool?

Comment: This is off topic - it has nothing to do with Android, and everything to do with your network.  The answer is either a) all addresses matching the netmask are *valid*, b) those addresses which respond to traffic *of a particular type* are *in use*, or c) ask the *unspecified* DNS server for a list through some special interface *that may (or more likely) may not* exist.